# I think I am missing something

Tags: postgresql

I need to create an insert statement and it is not working? would love some help. I get no relation. Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO movies table (movie_id, release_year, movie_title,movie_descrption, number_in_stock_,rental_or_sale_or_both, rental_daily_rate)

INSERT INTO movies VALUES('10101', '1985','top gun', 'airplains', '50', 'both', '$5'
```

And here is my table

SQL database table for Movies tables

```
CREATE TABLE movies_id
(
    movie_id               VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    release_year           DATE NOT NULL,
    movie_title            VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    movie_description      VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    number_in_stock        VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    rental_or_sale_or_both VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    rental_daily_rate      VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Indent your code 4 characters

Comment: Remove the second *insert into* right before values

Comment: If ok, delete your question :-)

Comment: Let me see if it works

Comment: I am still getting an error message at movie ID: insert into rental (movie_id, release_year, movie_title,movie_description, number_in_stock_,rental_or_sale_or_both, rental_daily_rate)
                    (1001, 1989, 'topgun', 'planes', 50, 'both', $5);

Comment: `values` keyword is lost.

Comment: Is this MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server? Those are two very different dialects.

Comment: POSGRE SQL. I am still getting an error  by 1985.

Comment: You didn't write '')' at second insert query's end

Comment: I just did a test and I am still having issues.

Comment: INSERT INTO movies_id (movie_id, release_year, movie_title,movie_descrption, number_in_stock_,rental_or_sale_or_both, rental_daily_rate) VALUES('10101', '1985','top gun', 'airplains', '50', 'both', '$5');

Comment: I said remove *insert into* not *insert into values*

Answer (score 1):

`'1985'` is not a correct `DATE` value, some field names are mistyped. Try with following statements:

```
CREATE TABLE movies_id
(
    movie_id               VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    release_year           DATE NOT NULL,
    movie_title            VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    movie_description      VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    number_in_stock        VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    rental_or_sale_or_both VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    rental_daily_rate      VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO movies_id 
(movie_id, release_year, movie_title, movie_description, number_in_stock, 
       rental_or_sale_or_both, rental_daily_rate)
VALUES ('10101', '1985-01-01','top gun', 'airplains', '50', 'both', '$5')
```

[Working Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=23ddd1627a31afdeb34dd9c28debfdc5)

Comment: Let me try it really quickly.

Comment: Hi Giorgos, that worked thank you so much!

Comment: @ChrisPagratis Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped solve your problem.

Comment: I am able to add one row. How do you add 5 rows?

Comment: @ChrisPagratis You add another (  ...  ) set ... google `INSERT INTO`

Answer (score 0):

Try to this first create this table and run the insert syntax

```
Create Table movies(movie_id VARCHAR Not NULL PRIMARY key,
 release_year date not null,
 movie_title VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
 movie_description VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
 number_in_stock VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
 rental_or_sale_or_both VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
 rental_daily_rate VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);

insert into movies values('10101', '1985','top gun', 'airplains', '50', 'both', '$5');
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is:

```
INSERT INTO movies (movie_id, release_year, movie_title,movie_descrption, number_in_stock_,rental_or_sale_or_both, rental_daily_rate) VALUES('10101', '1985','top gun', 'airplains', '50', 'both', '$5')
```

or short version insert (considering the  creation'  order of attributes in table)

```
INSERT INTO movies VALUES('10101', '1985','top gun', 'airplains', '50', 'both', '$5')
```

Comment: Hi Luis, I tried it I am still getting a ( error. I am using Postgre SQL.

Comment: You forgot the last ")". I add in my example! 

Verify too if this is name correct (with underline in end): number_in_stock_

Comment: other point is: you need to remove the "table" word. INSERT INTO movies...  not INSERT INTO movie table. 

Remember,  tables name not have whitespace!